# Highcharts nodeName of undefined

Tags: javascript, html, prototypejs, highcharts, scriptaculous

When playing around with a chart generated by highcharts, and exporting it to SVG, I get a lot of errors, about 1000 (nodeName of undefined) per 6 seconds

**The code responsible is this:**

```
element = wrapper.element,
nodeName = element.nodeName, // <---- Here (Cannot read property 'nodeName' of undefined)
renderer = wrapper.renderer,
skipAttr,
attrSetters = wrapper.attrSetters,
shadows = wrapper.shadows,
hasSetSymbolSize,
ret = wrapper;
```

**The stacktrace** (in Chrome 17.0.963)

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeName' of undefined
SVGElement.attr highcharts.src.js:2008
init.Effect.HighchartsTransition.Class.create.update prototype-adapter.src.js:86
(anonymous function) effects.js:1
Effect.Base.Class.create.loop effects.js:1
Effect.ScopedQueue.Class.create.loop effects.js:1
b prototype.js:1
```

**The fiddle to re-create** : [here](http://jsfiddle.net/epoch/6c2qE/), to reproduce click the series on/off and then click on the `My Download` link, switch on/off again and click on the `My Download` link again.

My question is as follows, is this my code, or a bug in highcharts; and how can I fix it?

Comment: I should also mention this only happens when scriptaculous is included

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the answer I was looking for; It was a bug in highcharts, fixed [here](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/835)

Answer (score 0):

I am not really familiar with Prototype framework, but I did some tests and look at this code:

```
function getGraphSVG(options) {
    var svg;
    if (window.charts) {
        window.charts.each(function(pair) {
            svg = pair.value.getSVG(options);
            throw $break;
        });
    }

    return svg;
}
```

Somehow this `each` method returns 2 objects, one being `undefined`. So do the simple check:

```
if (pair.value)
     svg = pair.value.getSVG(options);
```

or in one line

```
pair.value && ( svg = pair.value.getSVG(options) );
```

and it should work.